# Android NDK error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before 'trig'

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm developing android app, since I've to use celt audio codec which is unavailable on android codec, I decide to use JNI, and I got the following issues (i'm new to C)

```
D:/adt-bundle-windows-x86/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/add-application.mk:128: Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 4 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
"Compile thumb : celt-0.11.1 <= bands.c
In file included from jni/celt-0.11.1/libcelt/modes.h:36:0,
                 from jni/celt-0.11.1/libcelt/bands.h:34,
                 from jni/celt-0.11.1/libcelt/bands.c:35:
jni/celt-0.11.1/libcelt/mdct.h:52:40: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before 'trig'
```

here is the source code

```
#ifndef MDCT_H
#define MDCT_H

#include "kiss_fft.h"
#include "arch.h"

typedef struct {
   int n;
   int maxshift;
   const kiss_fft_state *kfft[4];
   const kiss_twiddle_scalar * restrict trig;  //mdct.h line 52
} mdct_lookup;
```

I got the same error in many other lines like this

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'X'
```

the code

```
celt_norm * restrict X, * restrict Y;
```

Comment: It looks like the compiler doesn't support `restrict` keyword and treats it as the variable name. Try removing `restrict` and recompiling. Is there any specific reason why you require `restrict`?

Comment: @AleksG I don't know, it comes with the library